# Boto3 ec2 describe_images is too slow

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have this code snippet to get amazon machine images:

```
session.client('ec2', region_name=AWS_DEFAULT_REGION).describe_images(ExecutableUsers=[
               'all',
           ],
           Filters=[
               {
                   'Name': 'platform',
                   'Values': [
                       'windows',
                   ]
               },
               {
                   'Name': 'state',
                   'Values': [
                       'available',
                   ]
               },
               {
                   'Name': 'image-type',
                   'Values': [
                       'machine',
                   ]
               },
               {
                   'Name': 'virtualization-type',
                   'Values': [
                       'hvm',
                   ]
               },
               {
                   'Name': 'root-device-type',
                   'Values': [
                       'ebs',
                   ]
               },
           ],
           Owners=[
               '679593333241', # all public ami's from amazon as owner
           ])
```

This works, but the response is too slow, I know that the AMI list is very long, but i don't need all AMIs on the list, i only need the most popular AMI elements (red hat, amazon linux, centos, etc.) if i use Owners=['self'] it returns null, how do i make a sort list of AMI elements like in aws console in quickstart menu when launch a new instance(see the image)? this list has 38 elements.

[image: quickstart menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `describe_images()`, you might want to use a special feature of **Amazon EC2 Systems Manager - Parameter Store** that can provide the AMI ID of recent Amazon-managed AMIs.

For example:

```
aws ssm get-parameters --names /aws/service/ecs/optimized-ami/amazon-linux-2/recommended --region us-east-1
```

Returns:

```
{
    "Parameters": [
        {
            "Name": "/aws/service/ecs/optimized-ami/amazon-linux-2/recommended",
            "Type": "String",
            "Value": "{\"schema_version\":1,\"image_name\":\"amzn2-ami-ecs-hvm-2.0.20181017-x86_64-ebs\",\"image_id\":\"ami-0a6be20ed8ce1f055\",\"os\":\"Amazon Linux 2\",\"ecs_runtime_version\":\"Docker version 18.06.1-ce\",\"ecs_agent_version\":\"1.21.0\"}",
            "Version": 1,
            "LastModifiedDate": 1539908415.817,
            "ARN": "arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1::parameter/aws/service/ecs/optimized-ami/amazon-linux-2/recommended"
        }
    ],
    "InvalidParameters": []
}
```

See:

- [Query for the latest Amazon Linux AMI IDs using AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/query-for-the-latest-amazon-linux-ami-ids-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/)
- [Query for the Latest Windows AMI Using Systems Manager Parameter Store | AWS Management Tools Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/query-for-the-latest-windows-ami-using-systems-manager-parameter-store/)
- [Working with Public Parameters - AWS Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/parameter-store-public-parameters.html)